# Is it a right way to write a Generic protocol that contain another Generic protocol

Tags: ios, swift

I try to describe a protocol with associatedtype like below:

```
protocol SomeViewRelativeProtocol {
    associatedtype ViewType: UIView
    
    var view: ViewType
}


protocol SomeProtocolContainMultipleSomeViewRelativeProtocol {
   var views: [SomeViewRelativeProtocol]

// error :  Protocol 'SomeViewRelativeProtocol' 
// can only be used as a generic constraint because 
// it has Self or associated type requirements
}
```

so I can use those protocol like this:

```
class Button: SomeViewRelativeProtocol {
    var view: UIButton = UIButton()
}

class Label: SomeViewRelativeProtocol {
    var view: UILabel = UILabel()
}

// then I want do some thing like this

class SomeContainer: SomeProtocolContainMultipleSomeViewRelativeProtocol {
   var views: [SomeViewRelativeProtocol] = []
   
   func add() {
       self.views.append(Button())
       self.views.append(Label())
   }


   func do() {
        self.views.forEach { (item) in
            item.view.frame = .zero
        }
   }
}
```

how can I describe this situation, I have tried to create a AnyView class, to make swift know the type like below, but when implement the subclass(Button: AnyView) of AnyView, then Cannot convert value of type Button to AnyView:

```
class AnyView: SomeViewRelativeProtocol {
    var view: UIView = UIView()
}


class Button: AnyView {
   var view: UIButton = UIButton()
}

class Label: AnyView {
   var view: UILabel = UIButton()
}

class SomeContainer: SomeProtocolContainMultipleSomeViewRelativeProtocol {
    var views: [AnyView] = []


    func add() {
       self.views.append(Button())
       self.views.append(Label())
       // Cannot convert value of type ....

   }
}
```

Is there a right way to do it? or I'm wrong at the beginning?

=============================== Updata ===============================

I came up with an idea:

```
protocol SomeViewRelativeProtocol {
    associatedtype ViewType: UIView
    
    var view: ViewType
}


protocol SomeProtocolContainMultipleSomeViewRelativeProtocol {
   // var views: [SomeViewRelativeProtocol]
   // change it to 
   var views: [Any] { get }
   func add<T: SomeViewRelativeProtocol>(item: T) -> Void
   func itemAtIndex<T: SomeViewRelativeProtocol>(index: Int) -> T?
}
```

how about that, I don't know how to do the same thing like function use `<T: SomeViewRelativeProtocol>` on property

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do something like that :

```
protocol SomeViewRelativeProtocol {
    var view: UIView {get}
}


protocol SomeProtocolContainMultipleSomeViewRelativeProtocol {
   var views: [SomeViewRelativeProtocol] {get}
}

class Button: SomeViewRelativeProtocol {
    var view: UIView = UIButton()
}

class Label: SomeViewRelativeProtocol {
    var view: UIView = UILabel()
}
```

Also, right now it doesn't work because of a compiler limitation, more than a conceptual limitation
It's also related to : https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-522

Comment: What is it for those with the same issue?

Comment: I notice that a  function can do something like `func name<T: SomeViewRelativeProtocol >(view: T) -> void`  so I think I can change property into function to achieve the same purpose

Comment: The problem is that generic function are, to simplify, a different function for each type T.
So the function name<Button> is not the same as name<Label> and you'll need to store the property somewhere and this property will need to be typed as well.

Comment: Yes, you are right, so I think maybe I can avoid use typed property instead a property with Any type `var views: [Any] {get}` then implement some necessary functions like `func add<T: SomeViewRelativeProtocol >(view: T) -> void` and `func view<T: SomeViewRelativeProtocol >(at index: Int) -> T?` how about that

Comment: If you type it with UIView like in my answer it will work and allow you to have the base type. Using AnyType is really not a good idea except in some very specific case where you can indeed have any type.